# Custom swipe Listview in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to create a custom list view containing save and delete buttons on swiping the each row right and left in xamarin.android, can any one suggest me the standard way ,i'm new to the xamarin.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [SwipeListView](https://components.xamarin.com/view/android-swipelistview) component which supports Swipe events.

Comment: Thank you @Luis beltran...but how can i edit that component to make it work as gmail app to delete row and undo row on a listview??

Answer (score 0):

If you use the new CoordinatorLayout as show in xamarin Evolve, you can also use the new SwipeDismissBehavior.

ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/SwipeDismissBehavior.html

Comment: thanks for replay  , can u suggest an example source code?